# Cannot install Sketchup with Wine / TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine

I'm having problems installing SketchUp 2016 with wine.

This is the problem I get:

```
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"CustomWelcomeDlg" returned 1602
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got first two error like you got when i ran iexplorer from wine by

```
wine iexplore.exe "https://example.com"
```

but was able to solve only one 
i.e

```
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

above error can be solve by installing winbind package

```
sudo apt-get install winbind
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get install libntlm0`.

Comment: There is no package with that name. Which of these did you mean? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ntlm0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: oops... updated.